# spring- i dont see dist or projects folder in sts 3.5 distribution software nor any xml files

Tags: xml, spring

I am new to spring.
       In a video tutorial ,I saw that, after downloading sts bundle, go to 
dist folder , go to projects folder and there will be xml files.
        Unfortunately, i dont see any of the above folders, nor any xml files that will give projects / samples.
         My Eclipse version: kepler
         My spring distribution : sts-bundle-3.5
         Windows -32 bit.

Unfortunately , I am not able to see any help why they are not there.

Please help.

Thanks a lot,
Bhaskar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring has moved much of their code to GitHub and since they've made the move it's not always easy to find what you're looking for, especially if you're referencing older material.

Here's a search on GitHub under the Spring Projects that might help you find what you're looking for. The first result ("spring-integration-samples") is probably your best bet.

https://github.com/spring-projects?query=samples

If you have already searched the web and can't quite find what you're looking for, point out what you've already tried in your question and provide some specifics. For example, was there a specific sample project you were looking for?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and detailed reply. Actually, I am learning from video tutorial, where ,the tutor is explaining that I can take DTD tag line from samples ( actually, he is starting with that, he will explain XSD version later, it appears).So, he was pointing to a dist folder and was able to go to "projects" folder, with many "applicationContext.xml" files, each for each of those sample projects.However, I could not find any , in my 3.5 spring distribution.I thought, some explanation regarding that move by spring would help. Now, by your explanation, I am quite satisfied.Thankslot.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want the DTD tag, here it is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
```